# Ionic framework version mission

Tags: git, ionic-framework, command-line-interface, ionic2

When I typed `ionic-info`, I was missing `Ionic Framework version` but everything else was showing. Does anybody know why this is so.

Related or not, apps built on a teammates machine worked well (he had the Ionic Framework Version) but when the same app was built on mine, it showed a white screen

Answer (score 0):

ionic info should give system info regarding environment and cli
 $ ionic info

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 5.1.1

Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0

Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.0

Ionic CLI Version: 1.6.1

Ionic App Lib Version: 0.3.3

ios-deploy version: 1.7.0

ios-sim version: 3.1.1

OS: Mac OS X Yosemite

Node Version: v0.12.5

Xcode version: Xcode 6.4 Build version 6E35b

But  although ionic framework version doesn't affect the running  of application in most cases it must be plugin issues or  read this article

How To Debug The White Screen Of Death In Your Ionic App
https://gonehybrid.com/how-to-debug-the-white-screen-of-death-in-your-ionic-app/

But can you check what are you getting any errors in your console?

You can debug in chrome or in safari